# Display the image through javascript on client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, caching

I am building a website where I have to display the profile picture of a user multiple times on page like 10 to 15 times.The profile image size is 80Kb and it is fetched from a url(not present on my server). Displaying it multiple times increases the browser requests consequently increases page size. Is there any method available to display the image through javascript on client side so that the image is downloaded only once and saved to some variable to be displayed multiple times. Or if you know some better option it will be highly appreciated. Thanks alot.

Comment: how do you currently display the image

Comment: @AnandSiddharth Currently displaying its url in php through echo and using img src tag

Comment: @zish . Till now what you have tried. Please share your code & try to provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @zish if the url remains same for all img tags (i.e. wherever you are placing the image in the webpage multiple times with same resource url) then the browser doesn't requests for the same resource again and again, it caches for current session. You don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_store_images_using_localstorage57?lang=en

on logout you can clear storage

```
<script>
      var hero;

      if ( localStorage.getItem('heroImg')) {
        hero = localStorage.getItem('heroImg');
      }
      else {
        hero = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7    /.../    6p+3dIR//9k=';
        localStorage.setItem('heroImg',hero);
      }

      document.getElementById("hero-graphic").src='data:image/png;base64,' + hero;
    </script> 


    <img id="hero-graphic" alt="Blog Hero Image" src="" />
```

here  `hero = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7    /.../    6p+3dIR//9k=';` you can get your profile picture link through ajax